# Mysqli select average of count query

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to get the average number of unique items sold. The database structure is like:

```
ID    ItemSize    ItemColor    DateSold
```

If I do this query:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS COUNT FROM store_sales GROUP BY ItemSize, ItemColor
```

... This will give me the total sold for each item whose size and color are the same.

I need to get the AVERAGE of all the numbers in this result set. How would I do this?

** Sample Data **

`store_sales`:

```
ID    ItemSize    ItemColor
1     3           5
2     3           5
3     2           5
4     2           6
5     2           6
6     2           6
```

Query:

```
Select Count(*) AS COUNT FROM store_sales GROUP BY ItemSize, ItemColor
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [Count] => 2 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [Count] => 1 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [Count] => 3 ) 
)
```

I am attempting to get the average. I would like to return `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your query as subquery for the `AVG`, and dont name a column `COUNT` that is a reserved word.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19de57/4)**

```
SELECT AVG(ITEM_COUNT)
FROM (
        SELECT Count(*) AS ITEM_COUNT
        FROM store_sales 
        GROUP BY ItemSize, ItemColor
     ) T
```

Comment: That is how I thought I should do it, but when I do, nothing is returned.

Comment: Can you include some sample data?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I was forgetting the `T` at the end of the query... What does that do, exactly?

Comment: That create an alias to the subquery. so you can reference on other places... is similar to `FROM YourTableName T` But in this case the table is a query.